# JOIN on multilple rows to SELECT only TOP row in SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a table which has only 1 row per ID/Date while the other one can have overlapping ID/Dates.  I need to JOIN them in such a way that only top row is selected (actually any row from duplicates table is fine!).  Its fairly easy to do this in 2 steps (Insert & Update) but I'm looking if it can be done in a single step.

```
CREATE TABLE #Row1Each (ID VARCHAR(10), Date_ DATETIME, Value FLOAT) INSERT   INTO #Row1Each SELECT 'AAPL', '1/10/2015', 100 INSERT INTO #Row1Each SELECT 'MSFT', '1/10/2015', 20
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (ID VARCHAR(10), Date_ DATETIME, Qty FLOAT) INSERT INTO #Table1 SELECT 'AAPL', '1/10/2015', 55000
CREATE TABLE #Duplicates (ID VARCHAR(10), StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME, Quote FLOAT) INSERT INTO #Duplicates SELECT 'AAPL', '1/2/2015', '12/31/2016', 0.1 INSERT INTO #Duplicates SELECT 'AAPL', '1/4/2015', '10/05/2016', 0.11

/*
    AAPL    2015-01-10 00:00:00.000     100
    MSFT    2015-01-10 00:00:00.000     20

    AAPL    2015-01-10 00:00:00.000     55000

    AAPL    2015-01-02 00:00:00.000     2016-12-31 00:00:00.000     0.1
    AAPL    2015-01-04 00:00:00.000     2016-10-05 00:00:00.000     0.1
*/

SELECT  A.*
    ,   B.Qty
    ,   C.Quote  
FROM    #Row1Each A
        LEFT JOIN #Table1 B ON B.ID = A.ID 
                           AND B.Date_ = A.Date_
        LEFT JOIN #Duplicates C ON C.ID = A.ID 
                               AND A.Date_ BETWEEN C.StartDate AND C.EndDate

DROP TABLE #Row1Each DROP TABLE #Table1 DROP TABLE #Duplicates

/*  Desired output
    AAPL    2015-01-10 00:00:00.000     100     55000   0.1
    MSFT    2015-01-10 00:00:00.000     20      NULL    NULL
*/
```

Comment: Please post your expected output with the correct format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `APPLY`.

```
SELECT
    r.Id,
    r.Date_,
    r.Value,
    t.Qty,
    d.Quote
FROM #Row1Each r
LEFT JOIN #Table1 t
    ON t.ID = r.ID
    AND t.Date_ = r.Date_
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #Duplicates d
    WHERE 
        d.ID = r.ID
        AND r.Date_ BETWEEN d.StartDate AND d.EndDate
    ORDER BY EndDate DESC -- Returns Top 1 Based on EndDate
)d
```